# convert a list to a nested list with parent-children relation in Java 8 by stream

Tags: java, recursion, java-8, java-stream

The Arraylist is like below:

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "parent_id": 0,
  "name": "Top1",
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "parent_id": 1,
  "name": "Second Layer1",
},{
  "id": 3,
  "parent_id": 0,
  "name": "Top2",
},{
  "id": 4,
  "parent_id": 1,
  "name": "Second Layer2",
}]
```

The output should be like:

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "parent_id": 0,
  "name": "Top1",
  "children": [{
    "id": 2,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "name": "Second Layer1",
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "name": "Second Layer2",
  }]
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "parent_id": 0,
  "name": "Top2",
}]
```

My current solution is that distinguishing "top layers" and "second layers", then converting the "second layers" to a hashmap group by "parent_id", finally iterating the "top layers" and match up the id of "top layer" with the key of that hashmap.
The implementation is like blew:

```
List<Org> topLayers = list.stream().filter(org -> org.getParent_id==0).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Org> secondLayers = list.stream().filter(org -> org.getParent_id!=0).collect(Collectors.toList());

Map<Long, List<Org>> hashMap = secondLayers.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Org::parent_id));

topLayers.stream().forEach(topOrg -> {
    topOrg.setChildren(hashMap.get(topOrg.getId()));
});
```

As you could see, it costs 4 steps to figure out.
Is there a more effective way to solve it?

*Extension:* What if is there more than 2 layers? like recursive

Comment: Is it necessary you need ```Streams``` to accomplish this? Or can you implement a better data structure like a ```Tree Node``` to do this

Answer (score 4):

You also can do like this

```
Map<Long, Org> hashMap = list.stream()
                .filter(org -> org.getParent_id!=0)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Org::parent_id));
List<Org> listWithChilds = list.stream()
                .filter(org -> org.getParent_id==0)
                .map(topOrg -> {
                    topOrg.addChildren(hashMap.get(topOrg.getId()));
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply group all your data using group by based on parentID then assign each parent to that list:

```
Map<Long, List<Org>> result = list.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Org::parent_id));
```

then:

```
list.stream().filter(org -> org.getParent_id==0).forEach(v -> {
    v.addChildren(result.get(v.getId()));
});
```

There can we many way to do this. You can try others too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [online demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Bkx00CWJU) . you can do this by using `forEach` and then useing `filter`

```
originalList.forEach(el->{
        int parentId = Integer.parseInt(el.get("parent_id").toString());
        if(parentId>0) {
            List<Map<String, Object>> childList = originalList.stream().filter(e->Integer.parseInt(el.get("id").toString())==parentId).collect(Collectors.toList());
            if(!childList.isEmpty()) {
                el.put("children",childList );
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You already said it, recursive.

```
convert(List src, List target) {
    for each item with parent id as (target is empty ? 0 : target's id):
        add it to (target is empty ? target : target's children)
        convert(src, item)
}
```